# How to concatenate text with dynamic length in CODEIGNITER?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dynamic, concatenation, ellipsis

How do I concatenate the expected text with varying length?

I have already placed `$this->load->helper('text');` in my controller. The closest example shown in ellislab page is:

```
$str = 'this_string_is_entirely_too_long_and_might_break_my_design.jpg';
echo ellipsize($str, 32, .5);
```

According to the explanation, this will produce: this_string_is_e…ak_my_design.jpg .

However, in my case, I do not have a fixed string to be concatenated. What I need to concatenate is a description element which length can vary depending on user input.

```
<td class="first" width="200px"><a href="<?= site_url() ?>/provider/view_job/<?= $row['job_id'] ?>"><?= $row['description'] ; ?></a></td>
```

How should I adjust  line to have its result concatenated?

Thank you for any possible help here.

Comment: I think you're using "concatenate" incorrectly. To concatenate two strings means to join them together, one after the other. In PHP this is done with the dot operator: $a="aaa"; $b="bbb"; $a.$b="aaabbb"; Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Oh, I see. I mistook that. Yes, but what I need is almost similar. For example, a user will input this text:  "This is an example description to be shown on my page. This may seem quite long so I think it's best if this can be cut by adding ... at the end, but once clicked, a new page will show this whole description." This is what I need. And like I wrote earlier, the length of this input can vary depending on user.. Kindly help me figure it out.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you can use a PHP function strlen: https://www.php.net/strlen

**strlen — Get string length**

so for your code / example you can do this:

```
ellipsize($str, strlen($str)/2, .5);
```

or in your case:

```
<?= ellipsize($row['description'], strlen($row['description'])/2, .5); ?>
```

---

Also if you don't want to use CodeIgniter's function, you can use PHP's sub_str: https://www.php.net/substr

```
substr("abcdef", 0, -1);  // returns "abcde"
```

So for your code it would be something like:

```
 <?= substr($row['description'], 0, strlen($row['description'])/2) . '...'; ?>
```

Comment: Hi @NikkoR. Thanks for your reply.. I tried to use that pattern but it did not work.. This is the line where I should do the "concatenation".. <td class="first" width="200px"><a href="<?= site_url() ?>/provider/view_job/<?= $row['job_id'] ?>"><?= $row['description'] ; ?></a></td> I should "concatenate" the description..

Comment: @user3453256 have you tried <?= ellipsize($row['description'], strlen($row['description']), .5); ?> ?

Comment: I retried, <td class="first" width="250px"><a href="<?= site_url() ?>/provider/view_job/<?= $row['job_id'] ?>">  <?= ellipsize($row['description'], strlen($row['description']), .5); ?></a></td>  but same result..   no effect on the text shown in my table..

Comment: Oh gosh, @NikkoR, thanks! <?= substr($row['description'], 0, 30) . '...'; ?> worked! Thanks a lot! This is my second post, and first successful one here. Thanks for your help! Have a great day!! :)

Comment: no problem @user3453256, I was to updated the ellipsize function and it should be something like `ellipsize($str, strlen($str)/2, .5);`

Comment: I see.. That would be really useful! BTW, do you happen to also know the solution to my other post? It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612375/add-edit-and-delete-issues-in-codeigniter/22612920?noredirect=1#comment34433856_22612920

Comment: Unfortunately I can't comment there.. but does the post data really able to reach until the model part? I usually process my post data on my controller.